# Ищу бесплатное API для карт Android

Tags: android, yandex-maps-api, google-maps-api, карты, поиск-api

Подскажите бесплатное АПИ для разработки Андроид приложения с картами для коммерческого использования. Должны быть постройка маршрутов и метки

Comment: OpenStreetMap. не знаю, как насчет именно под Android, то для Web'а у них точно есть. но обычно "бесплатно" и "для коммерческого" не могут стоят в одном предложении))

Answer (score 1):

Коммерческое коммерческому - рознь. Лучше уточнить вопрос, что именно под этим подразумевается.

[MapKit](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/mapkit/doc/intro/concepts/conditions.html) в целом не запрещает использование в коммерческих проектах. Например приложение магазина может использовать API бесплатно, если его может скачать любой пользователь и получить доступ к карте до момента оплаты.

Но если приложение само по себе закрытое или платное, или таковым будет доступ к карте и данным API, то вопрос точно не про API Яндекс.Карт и метку **yandex-maps-api** можно удалять.